# In a Euclidean ring, $d(a) = d(1)$ iff $a$ is a unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a Euclidean ring, $d(a) = d(1)$ iff $a$ is a unit

Here is my attempt at proving this.

First, $a$ is a unit $\implies d(a) = d(1)$

$d(1) \le d(1 \cdot a) = d(a) \le d(1 \cdot a \cdot a^{-1}) = d(1 \cdot 1) = d(1)$.

Now $d(a) = d(1) \implies a$ is a unit.

$d(a) = d(1) \le d(ab)$

Consider the case when $d(1) = d(ab)$

Now $d$ is a function that maps $1$ to some value $c$. $d$ also maps $ab$ to $c$ and hence we can take $ab$ such that $ab = 1$. I.e. $a$ is a unit.

Is that ok? Is there a nicer way of phrasing the last part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't be sure such a $b$ exists when you say "the case where $d(1) = d(ab)$".

It is easier to use the division algorithm: Let $1 = qa + r$. We know that either $r = 0$ or $d(r) < d(a)$. But $d(a) = d(1)$ is minimal (have you shown this?). So $r = 0$ and $1 = qa$, making $a$ a unit.

Comment: Ok I see that now. But how would you show $d(a) = d(1)$ is minimal, i.e. that $a$ is minimal. $(1)$ will generate the entire ring, but I can't see how to get from that to saying $a$ will generate the entire ring?

Comment: Wait, I may be misunderstanding something. Is $d$ your norm function, or is a function applied to ideals?

Comment: If it's the norm function, let $x \in R$. $d(x) = d(x \cdot 1) \ge d(1)$, so $d(1)$ is a minimal norm.

Comment: It's the norm function, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The second part needs improvement.
Clearly $a\ne0$ if $d(a)=1\ne 0$. Thus by division with remainder, there exist $q,r$ with $1=qa+r$ with $d(r)<d(a)$. As this implies $d(r)=0$ we obtain $r=0$ and hence $1=qa$.